# Referencing from a Datatable

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable, self-reference

I have a datatable called gpsdata with 3 string columns "Image", "Latitude", "Longitude". I am trying to read a specific row and column value using `string s = DataTable.Rows [3] [ "Latitude"];`but I am getting an error. What is the correct way to reference a datatable in the same way an array is referenced `gpsdata[0, 0]`?

Many thanks Steve

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Red wiggly line under DataTable.Rows and 'spanner' icon message An Object reference is require for the non-static field, method, or property 'DataTableRows'

Comment: That's because you are using `DataTable` the class not your instance. Check it,  I bet your variable name is `dataTable`...

Comment: @Ofir not sure what you mean, my datatable is called gpsdata. Can you explain a bit more? .. :)

Comment: @GrantWinney oh yes... it's in the question how can i miss it,  i guess i lost the bet :-)

Comment: @SteveGalvin use `gpsdata.Rows [3] [ "Latitude"];`